# Docker Image Creation Using Copy Command

Tags: image, docker

My Dockerfile:
I'm using the copy command in the docker file.

```
FROM java:8-jdk-alpine
COPY ./target/microservice-demo-1.jar microservice-demo-1.jar
EXPOSE 8085
RUN sh -c "touch microservice-demo-1.jar"
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","microservice-demo-1.jar"]
```

When I'm trying to run this Dockerfile it gives me an error at Step 2/5
refer the snapshot:

```
Step 1/5 : FROM java:8-jdk-alpine
8-jdk-alpine: Pulling from library/java
709515475419: Pull complete
38a1c0aaa6fd: Pull complete
5b58c996e33e: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:d49bf8c44670834d3dade17f8b84d709e7db47f1887f671a0e098bafa9bae49f
Status: Downloaded newer image for java:8-jdk-alpine
 ---> 3fd9dd82815c
Step 2/5 : COPY ./target/microservice-demo-1.jar microservice-demo-1.jar
COPY failed: stat /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/tmp/docker-builder908791064/target/microservice-demo-1.jar: no such file or directory
ubuntu@ip-172-31-34-222:~/dockerfile$
```

Comment: Could you show your project tree? Where the Dockerfile and the jar are located? By the way, why are you calling the touch command at 4th line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In dockerfile, try with below.

> COPY ./host-or-local-path /docker-container-full-path

It should work.